# Need to identify the brand of this kitchen faucet

Tags: faucet

I need to replace the diverter and/or cartridge and need the brand to get instructions/parts. There are no markings/logos on faucet or beneath the sink.

[image]Can anyone help?

Comment: It seems distinctive enough that some google searches might find it.  The spring used for the bend is one.  A fast search found this.  Kraus KPF-1603BGMB Artec Pro.  It looks close but different finish.

Comment: Markings (if there are any) may be very subtle and easy to miss.

Comment: FACAZ possibly https://www.amazon.ca/Kitchen-Faucets-Drinking-Sprayer-Purifier/dp/B0922PMZXN?dplnkId=51b3114c-7427-47fe-894e-5010a9931fe6